# Installing and running Wheel file Pypi

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

I have a python tool that I run from the terminal and I would like to upload it as a bdist on Pypi to make a ready to use tool. (like an .exe on Windows)

While uploading it to Pypi (the test version of the service) I've used the command `python -m build` which creates both the .tar.gz and .whl file.
When doing `pip install MyTool` it installs the tool as a package, hence I cannot execute it from terminal (I mean just by calling the name of the package), I can execute it by running `python3 path_to_....MyTool/MyTool.py` but this is not what the end-user is supposed to do.

The goal is to have:

- `pip install MyTool` (to install it)
- `MyTool` or `./MyTool` (to execute it)

I've tried to use the command `python3 -m build --wheel` in order to just create the .whl file and upload it to a new project without the .tar.gz file but still doing `pip install MyTool` it just installs the package (which i can import into my file) but I can't execute from terminal with `./MyTool`.

I include to screen to help solve the question:

[Screen of the .toml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY3Ih.png) 
[Screen of the setup.cfg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJJAg.png)

How to make MyTool into a ready to use python application?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

the `setup.cfg` file was missing the `options.entry_points`:

`[options.entry_points]`
`console_scripts = tool = MyTool:main`

The syntax for entry points is specified as follows:

`<name> = [<package>.[<subpackage>.]]<module>[:<object>.<object>]`

url: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html